# Problem with math typesetting in a BibTeX export of Google Scholar

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using BibTex for my bibliography, for citing I'm using google scholar. I'm mainly having problems with math symbols: for example, one of the references is
[image]

and I get :

[image]

How can I fix math symbols?

Answer (score 3):

For mysterious reasons, Google Scholar transforms `m^2` into `m\^{}2` and similarly for the other bits. Fix the entry as follows:

```
@article{murat2018exponential,
  title={On the exponential {Diophantine} equation {$(18m^2+1)^x+(7m2-1)^y=(5m)^z$}},
  author={Alan, Murat},
  journal={Turkish Journal of Mathematics},
  volume={42},
  number={4},
  pages={1990--1999},
  year={2018}
}
```

I've also added braces around the formula and the capitalized word, in order to avoid problems with styles that might capitalize or remove capitalization.

Also the author's name seems wrong: “Alan” is the family name and “Murat” is the given name. See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10998-020-00321-6.pdf for a confirmation.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.